Numerical Simulation of Diffusion Equation with Non-constant Diffusion Coefficient
Constant Case
The 1D diffusion equation with a constant diffusion coefficient reads:
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = D \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2}$$
This can be numerically simulated with the Backward Euler method:
$$\frac{\phi^{j+1}_i - \phi^{j}_i}{\Delta t} = D\frac{\phi^{j+1}_{i-1}-2\phi^{j+1}_{i} + \phi^{j+1}_{i+1}}{\Delta x^2}$$
Letting $\alpha = D\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^2}$
$$\phi^{j+1}_i - \phi^{j}_i = \alpha(\phi^{j+1}_{i-1}-2\phi^{j+1}_{i} + \phi^{j+1}_{i+1})$$
$$-\alpha \phi^{j+1}_{i-1} + (1+2\alpha)\phi^{j+1}_{i} -\alpha \phi^{j+1}_{i+1} = \phi^{j}_i$$
This is an implicit matrix equation:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
-\alpha & 1 + 2\alpha & -\alpha & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & -\alpha & 1 + 2\alpha & -\alpha & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -\alpha & 1 + 2\alpha & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & a_n &
\end{pmatrix}\phi^{j+1} = \phi^{j}$$
with the boundary conditions TBD. The matrix is a tridiagonal matrix and so this equation can be solved efficiently with the Thomas algorithm.
Non-constant Case
The 1D diffusion equation with a non-constant diffusion coefficient reads:
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(D \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\right)$$
Now, the discrete approximation to this is found by:
$$\frac{\phi^{j+1}_i - \phi^{j}_i}{\Delta t}\approx \left[D(x+\Delta x)\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x+\Delta x)-D(x-\Delta x)\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x-\Delta x)\right]/2\Delta x$$
$$\frac{\phi^{j+1}_i - \phi^{j}_i}{\Delta t}\approx \left[D(x+\Delta x)\left(\phi(x+2\Delta x)-\phi(x)\right)-D(x-\Delta x)\left(\phi(x)-\phi(x-2\Delta x)\right)\right]/4\Delta x^2$$
Now letting $\beta = D\frac{\Delta t}{4\Delta x^2}$, and again applying Backward Euler:
$$\phi^{j+1}_i - \phi^{j}_i= \beta \left[D_{i+1}\left(\phi^{j+1}_{i+2}-\phi^{j+1}_i \right)-D_{i-1}\left(\phi^{j+1}_{i}-\phi^{j+1}_{i-2}\right)\right]$$
$$-\beta D_{i-1} \phi^{j+1}_{i-2} + \left(1 + \beta (D_{i+1} + D_{i-1})\right) \phi^{j+1}_i - \beta D_{i+1} \phi^{j+1}_{i+2} = \phi^{j}_i$$
Again we will have an implicit matrix equation:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & 0 & b_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & a_2 & 0 & b_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
c_1 & 0 & a_3 & 0 & b_3 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & c_2 & 0 & a_4 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & c_3 & 0 & a_5 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & a_{n-3} & 0 & b_{n-3} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & a_{n-2} & 0 & b_{n-2} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & c_{n-3} & 0 & a_{n-1} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & c_{n-2} & 0 & a_n
\end{pmatrix} \phi^{j+1} = \phi^{j}$$
With again the boundary conditions TBD. The third, fourth, and fifth rows looks like:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-\beta D_2 & 0 & 1 + \beta D_2 + \beta D_4 & 0 & -\beta D_4 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -\beta D_3 & 0 & 1 + \beta D_3 + \beta D_5 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -\beta D_4 & 0 & 1 + \beta D_4 + \beta D_6 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Questions 1
Is there a name for this type of matrix? It is a pentadiagonal matrix, but it is almost a "pseudo-tridiagonal matrix" because there are only 3 non-zero diagonals. Additionally, have people looked into algorithms similar to the Thomas algorithm for efficiently solving this implicit matrix equation?
Questions 2
Is there any other way to approximate the derivatives which gives a tridiagonal matrix as a result? In order to have mass conservation, each the terms with $\beta$ in each column should sum to zero. For example, a matrix patterned like:
\begin{pmatrix}
a_i & b_i & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 \\
-D_1 - D_2 & D_1 + 2D_2 + D_3 & -D_2 - D_3 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots &0 \\
0 & -D_2 - D_3 & D_2 + 2D_3 + D_4 & -D_3 - D_4 & \cdots & \cdots &0 \\
0 & 0 & -D_3 - D_4 & D_3 + 2D_4 + D_5 & -D_4 - D_5 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -D_4 - D_5 & D_4 + 2D_5 + D_6 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & a_n
\end{pmatrix}

Your discretization of the nonconstant diffusion term is incorrect. The 3-point second derivative stencil is obtained by computing a central difference at $x_i$ with step size $\Delta x$, then another two central differences at $x_{i+1/2}$ and $x_{i-1/2}$ with step size $\Delta x$ for a final discretization of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(D(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \phi\right) = \frac{D_{i+1/2} \phi_{i+1} - (D_{i+1/2}+D_{i-1/2})\phi_i + D_{i-1/2} \phi_{i-1}}{\Delta x^2}$

@whpowell96 It is not incorrect. It is permissible to use step sizes of $\Delta x$ or step sizes of $2\Delta x.$ The problem with using step sizes of $\Delta x$ here is that I have only defined $D_0, D_1, D_2, ...$ for integers. So the expression $D_{i+1/2}$ does not make sense.

Your formulation is correct, but it will not transform into a tridiagonal system as you desire. The formulation I gave is tridiagonal and the half integer diffusion coefficients can be obtained via linear interpolation

To create a tridiagonal matrix, we start by applying two central differences to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(D \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \phi\right)$ to obtain
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(D \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \phi\right) \approx \frac{D_{i+1/2}\phi_{i+1} - (D_{i+1/2}+D_{i-1/2})\phi_i + D_{i-1/2}\phi_{i-1}}{\Delta x^2},
$$
where $D_{i\pm 1/2} = D(x_{i\pm 1/2})$. If $D$ is only available on a fixed grid, you can apply linear interpolation $D(x_{i+1/2}) = \frac{D_{i+1} + D_i}{2}$ and $D(x_{i-1/2}) = \frac{D_{i} + D_{i-1}}{2}$, which results in
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(D \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \phi\right) \approx \frac{(D_{i+1}+D_i)\phi_{i+1} - (D_{i+1}+2D_i+D_{i-1})\phi_i+(D_i+D_{i-1})\phi_{i-1}}{2\Delta x^2}.
$$
The accuracy of this second method will be less since $D$ is approximated.
